# <ngx-tab tabTitle how to give color to string interpolation{{ }} in angular

Tags: angular, angular8

code:

```
<ngx-tab tabTitle="Data[{{empListById.length}}]" tabHeading [active]="activeEmpIndex === 1" [bypassDOM]="true">
```

i need to give color to only `{{empListById.length}}` not for whole `Data[{{empListById.length}}]`

example :
current result : Data[2]
expected result : Data[2] // 2 should be in green color